# How do I insert a column of static text into a nested dataframe in r?

Tags: r, nested-lists

Likely a trivial task for the pros out there, but have not been able to figure out how to insert the text found in the "Slug" column into each of the three nested tables associated with the slug.

![data] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/YClrE.png)

I am just looking to get the Slug value inserted into the nested tables and repeated for each row so I can combine and keep track of associations properly.

Any tips are most welcome! Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO! Questions get more attention if you explain what you've tried and what errors or incorrect results you are getting. It's best to include your code and simplified data that allows others to reproduce the issue you are running into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution

You can use `rowwise()` with `mutate(across())`

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(across(floor_price_array:holder_hist, ~list(mutate(.x,slug=slug))))
```

#### Explanation

If your original data, say `df`, looks like this:

```
  id    slug  floor_price_array num_listed_hist   holder_hist      
  <chr> <chr> <list>            <list>            <list>           
1 a     hyznu <tibble [10 x 3]> <tibble [10 x 3]> <tibble [10 x 3]>
2 b     awxeb <tibble [10 x 3]> <tibble [10 x 3]> <tibble [10 x 3]>
3 c     pbncj <tibble [10 x 3]> <tibble [10 x 3]> <tibble [10 x 3]>
```

then, the above code will add the value in the `slug` column as a new constant column in each of the nested `tibbles`, and resulting in this (notice that each now has four columns):

```
  id    slug  floor_price_array num_listed_hist   holder_hist      
  <chr> <chr> <list>            <list>            <list>           
1 a     hyznu <tibble [10 x 4]> <tibble [10 x 4]> <tibble [10 x 4]>
2 b     awxeb <tibble [10 x 4]> <tibble [10 x 4]> <tibble [10 x 4]>
3 c     pbncj <tibble [10 x 4]> <tibble [10 x 4]> <tibble [10 x 4]>
```

For example, `floor_price_array`, now contains this:

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 10 x 4
        x      y      z slug 
    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>
 1  1.44   2.02  -0.272 hyznu
 2 -0.598 -0.723 -0.528 hyznu
 3  0.490 -0.576 -1.62  hyznu
 4 -0.145  0.349  0.341 hyznu
 5 -0.362  0.503  0.584 hyznu
 6 -0.798 -0.839 -0.352 hyznu
 7 -0.503 -1.27  -1.18  hyznu
 8 -0.916 -0.654  0.335 hyznu
 9  0.578  0.137 -0.590 hyznu
10 -0.194 -0.674  1.73  hyznu

[[2]]
# A tibble: 10 x 4
         x        y       z slug 
     <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>
 1  0.876   0.665   -0.723  awxeb
 2 -0.0442 -0.00906  0.0829 awxeb
 3 -2.15    1.33     0.0692 awxeb
 4  0.264   0.237   -0.497  awxeb
 5  0.0381  0.0502  -1.58   awxeb
 6 -0.802   0.783   -1.34   awxeb
 7 -0.940   1.50    -0.542  awxeb
 8  0.209  -1.06     0.853  awxeb
 9  0.569  -1.15    -0.347  awxeb
10 -1.57   -0.0774   0.0250 awxeb

[[3]]
# A tibble: 10 x 4
          x       y       z slug 
      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>
 1 -0.0289  -1.63    1.29   pbncj
 2 -0.716    0.647   0.0230 pbncj
 3 -0.0797  -0.0227  2.12   pbncj
 4 -0.358   -1.43   -1.81   pbncj
 5 -1.35    -0.402  -0.463  pbncj
 6 -0.00494 -0.136   1.50   pbncj
 7  1.09     0.124  -0.974  pbncj
 8 -1.18     1.78   -0.836  pbncj
 9  0.896   -1.38    0.199  pbncj
10  0.293    0.420   0.562  pbncj
```

Input data:

```
df <- tibble(id = letters[1:3]
) %>%  
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(slug = paste0(sample(letters,5), collapse="")) %>% 
  mutate(floor_price_array=list(tibble(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10), z=rnorm(10))),
         num_listed_hist=list(tibble(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10), z=rnorm(10))),
         holder_hist=list(tibble(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10), z=rnorm(10)))
         ) %>% ungroup()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The explanation really helps me understand what is going on. Much appreciated once again.

Comment: great. pls select the answer/upvote etc, if it solves your problem